# IntelliJ + Git: File created in Branch B remains when switching to Branch A

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I have 2 branches, `A` and `B`, and both were created from `master`. On `A` I created a file `FileA`, did some commits, pushed to remote. While that's in PR, I swapped to `B`, created a new file `FileB` and did some work; however all I did was add it to Git, it hasn't had a commit yet.

In IntelliJ, when I swapped back to `A` to do some fix for the PR, `File B` appears in the project tree and inside the commit window. Why is that? How to resolve this?

Comment: Git won't delete untracked files if you switch branches. You can create a local commit on branch `B`, then the file will stay there.

Comment: @JanWilamowski worked perfectly; do you perhaps have any type of documentation explaining this in more detail?

Comment: how about https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch/2.23.0: "Switching branches does not require a clean index and working tree (i.e. no differences compared to HEAD). The operation is aborted however if the operation leads to loss of local changes, unless told otherwise with --discard-changes or --merge."